# ASP MVC Validation using RegularExpression for Combo Box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a combo box like this

```
<select name="Type" id="Type" >
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Open Ended">Open Ended</option>
  <option value="Property">Property</option>
</select>
```

and my MVC validator contains this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[^0]+", ErrorMessage = "Please Select the Type")]
public string Type { get; set; }
```

But when I submit the form there is no error thrown even when "--Select--" is selected. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify $ sign at the end of regex.

If that will not help try to skip value attribute in "--Select--" option (and it's content too):

```
<option label="--SELECT--"></option>
```

In that case your 'Required' attribute will raise validation error (because browser will post form parameter with unspecified value or will not post this parameter at all) - it helps in my case :)

Comment: Sorry guys ... I had the wrong name and id in my view that caused the problem ... I changed those thing and my RegEx works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<option value="0">--Select--</option>
```

into this:

```
<option value="">--Select--</option>
```

Now the required field validation attribute is the only one you need.